# Angular App Pulling in Entire Collection, Rather Than Finite # of Results as Expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pagination, observable

I am using observables in my Angular app to load data from our API. Because there is a lot to pull in, we're using ng2-pagination to handle pagination, and we're trying to set it up to pull data for each page that loads. So, in other words, initially we'd pull in the first 15 results for when the first page loads. Other pages would load data specific to those pages as well, only once the page number is clicked on.

Now, I can confirm this api call is working because when I run it in Postman, I get a finite set of results - rather than the whole collection - as expected.

However, that said, when I try and plug this in with the observable I'm using in the Angular app, I see that it's still pulling in the entire collection.

This is what I have for the api call (here 'page' represents page number, and 'pagesize' represents results per page):

```
getByCategory(category: string, page, pagesize) {
    const q = encodeURIComponent(stage);
    return this.http.get
    (`https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients/category/${q}?apikey=${this.key}&page=${this.page}&pagesize=${this.pagesize}`)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.stageErrorsHandler);
}
    stageErrorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

In my component I am subscribing like so, and requesting page 1, with 12 results returned:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.clientService.getByCategory('consulting', 1, 12)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            console.log(this.records);
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

Then, in the view, I am iterating over the array, and passing items through the pagination pipe like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records.data | paginate: { id: 'clients', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: page, totalItems: records.count }">

    <pagination-controls class="paginator" (pageChange)="page = $event" id="clients"
            maxSize="15"
            directionLinks="true"
            autoHide="true">
    </pagination-controls>
```

By the way, the api call is returning the total count as well as the array of objects - because the pagination tool uses that to determine how many pages to load. So the api looks like this - 'data' is the collection of records, and 'count' is the total number of records:

```
{
  "count": 10438,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "someId",
      "name": "someName"
    }
      ]
```

When I console log (this.records) in the ngOnInit life cycle, what returns is not a finite list of 12 results, as expected, but rather the entire collection. This is what I see in the console:

> Object {count: 10728, data: Array(4037)}

I'm not sure why I'm getting the entire collection. As I mentioned, this call works when I try it with Postman - but doesn't appear to be working as expected here.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here? Is there a problem with how I'm using the observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the resulting service call URL in Chrome dev tools' network tab? Does your URL template:

```
https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients/category/${q}?apikey=${this.key}&page=${this.page}&pagesize=${this.pagesize}
```

render correctly? Since you're passing params (category: string, page, pagesize) to the function, try reference them without "this." - e.g. ${page}

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure the call is constructed correctly. But I can check. What specifically do I access in Chrome dev-tools to see this?

Comment: This would show all network requests, including parameters passed and responses. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

Comment: Thanks, found it. Interestingly, that did point to the problem. In the constructed URL, both 'page' and 'pagesize' are returning 'undefined'. Now I need to figure out why that is. I will add this info to the question.

Comment: Right - since you're using this.page in the template. Remove "this." prefix from all the function parameter references, and it should work.

Comment: https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients/category/${q}?apikey=${this.key}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}

Comment: You're right, I forgot you posted it there. Yes, that was the correct answer.